# AngularJS http get not working with larger files

Tags: json, angularjs, http, get

I have an Angular controller which makes a call to $http.get.

```
app.controller('dataController', function dataController($scope,$http) {
$http.get(URL)
  .success(function(response) {$scope.jobs = response;});
});
```

This call works fine with small files but I have a json file that is 1.2MB in size (57,000 lines) that seems to be breaking my application. Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Are you trying to bind all 57k items? Does it hit your success method or does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

If you are two way binding to each element in each row then you will probably get a performance hit on the digest cycle.

Maybe you should page the data into the DOM.

ngGrid is good for this!

Or use angular 1.3 one way binding.